# how to use phpmailer to send attachment but I prefer to user mail()

Tags: php

I am trying to add some attachments using the `mail()` and would prefer to use this but is it true that phpmailer is a better choice for it? If so, I am trying to get phpmailer to work but have set the correct require path but it doesn't seem to find the files...

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use phpmailer\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer;
use phpmailer\PHPMailer\src\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'piano0011@hotmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'Grandpiano888';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('piano0011@hotmail.com', 'PianoCourse101');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBrHJ.png) is the path to the directories.

But is it possible to do it with `mail()` function?

Comment: You appear to be using `composer`, why not add `PHPMailer` as a dependency instead of including every required file manually?

Comment: Composer? I just copied the file from github and read that if I don't have composer, I should use require..

Comment: did I overlook something here?

Comment: Alternatively, if you're not using Composer, copy the contents of the PHPMailer folder into one of the include_path directories specified in your PHP configuration and load each class file manually:

<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
If you're not using the SMTP class explicitly (you're probably not), you don't need a use line for the SMTP class.

I

Comment: do you mean that I should use include_once instead of require?

Comment: `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` <- this is the composer autoloader, if a `vendor` directory exists in the same folder as the file you pasted along with `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, then you have composer installed, else remove this line or it will fail.

Comment: one more thing, i need to know the path of the file whose code you pasted before i can attempt an answer

Comment: I keep getting this error:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpmailer\PHPmailer\src\PHPMailer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\phpmailer.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\phpmailer.php on line 12

Comment: Do you need to know where I got the code from? I got it from github on this page

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I am just wondering... is it possible to send an attachment file using mail()?

Comment: do I need to add a lot of codes for that mail() because I am more familiar with it

Comment: To send an attachment with mail() function is way harder than you expect, for the sake of your time, try to use PHPMailer. Also when i asked `path of the file whose code you posted` i meant like `C:\\xampp\htdocs\somefile.php`

Comment: Since this site has a strict Q&A format, it's usually best to keep each question in a separate post. One of the questions on this page is about an error using PHPMailer; to get helpful answers, make sure such questions have a [mcve] - we don't need to see all your code, just the part you're trying to fix - and importantly, include the *exact error message* in the question. You can [edit] details in if you forget them at first.

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'phpmailer\PHPmailer\src\PHPMailer'
>   not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\phpmailer.php:12 Stack trace:
>   (#)0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\phpmailer.php on line 1

Your current namespace import is incorrect

```
<?php
   use phpmailer\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer; // Incorrect
   use phpmailer\PHPMailer\src\Exception; // Incorrect
```

Change your namespace imports to :

```
<?php
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```